# Is there any best way to transfer bulk data from Mysql to Mongodb?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am using MongoDB first time here. Is there any best way to transfer bulkdata from mysql into MongoDB. I try to search to in different ways but i did not find.

Comment: How about query data from MySQL and then save it into mongoDB using nodeJS or any other language you like?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to physically map all your mysql tables to documents in mongodb but you can use an already developed tool.

You can try: Mongify (http://mongify.com/)

It's a super simple way to transform your data from a MySql to MongoDB. It has a ton of support for changing your existing schema into a schema that would work better with MongoDB.

Mongify will read your mysql database, build a translation file for you and all you have to do is map how you want your data transformed.

It supports:

Updating internal IDs (to BSON ObjectID)
Updating referencing IDs
Typecasting values
Embedding Tables into other documents
Before filters (to change data manually before import)
and much much more...

There is also a short 5 min video on the homepage that shows you how easy it is.

Try it out and tell me what you think.
Please up vote if you find this answer helpful.